# What key shoud i pass as parameter to getSignedUrl from Amazon SDK

Tags: javascript, file-upload, amazon-s3

Im generating a pre-signed url so i can upload a file to a S3 bucket.

```
var params = {Bucket: 'xxxxxxx', Key: 'key', Expires: 60};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
console.log('The URL is', url);
```

The *Key* parameter is required, but i cant find in the documentation how can i generate this.

If i submit an upload using this generated URL:

```
xhr.open("PUT", url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', files[0].type);
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'authenticated-read');
xhr.send(files[0]);
```

It returns this error *SignatureDoesNotMatch*

Am i missing something on the url signing method?

Comment: Amazon should tell you what key to pass...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured this out.
Parameters to sign URL must have all the things that im sending on the header and the Key is the file name.

```
var params = {Bucket: 'xxxxxxx', Key: 'filename.ext', Expires: 60, ACL:'authenticated-read', ContentType: 'applicattion/xxxxx'};
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: hi, what is ACL?

Comment: ACL stands for "Access Control List". In amazon S3 you can specify the access on your files using this parameter.
You can find more info here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html